# is there a site offering a localised overview of all alternative browsers

Tags: localization, browser, progressive-enhancement

I would show IE6 visitors a site with limited css (Progressive Enhancement) but would also like them to gently show a header informing them they can/should upgrade to a modern browser. There are initiatives out there, like ie6nomore, who do just that. But the list of modern browsers and the headertext is hardcoded.
My site is localised, so I rather have a link to an external website, that autodetects their browser language, and informs them of modern browsers in their own langauge.
That way my 'advice' will always be up to date and fully localized.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a complete list, but Microsoft had to setup a [browser choise](http://www.browserchoice.eu/) page which shows the top 12 browsers, based on market share. This list will be re-evaluated every six months.

You can read more about this here:

- [Browser Choice FAQ](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/ff606439)

So if you detect an old browser, you could display a nice message and a link to this page.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

At least safari goes directly to the windows download, so its not really a universal solution.

And its only in english.

The browser landingpages are available in all languages, so so should be the browserchoice page. Unlike firefox and chrome apple doesn't have an auto browser language detecting landingpage, so I rerouted it via google search to achieve that.

(why can't I add this as a comment to the previous post?)